# How do I detect my GPU after fresh install?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu

Sorry if this has been asked already, I've checked all over but didn't find anything related to my problem (at least specifically, also, I'm a newbie).

Anyway, here goes, I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu (12.04) after some tragic mishaps. I reformatted the HDD and everything, install ran without a hitch, but upon logging in, my system can't seem to detect or locate my Geforce 560GTX card.

What can I do and what other information do I need to put up?

***Also, what are the commands to access them?***

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to detect or locate"?. Have you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-nvidia-video-drivers

Comment: Wait, do you have an Nvidia video card or an Ati one? since you mention the fglrx driver. Please read the link I provided for the Nvidia cards. For the Ati cards check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Comment: I have a Nvidia card, the fglrx driver is the only one I can see in 'Additional Drivers'

Comment: I noticed the first issue was that my monitor went to sleep after the install restarted my computer. I thought, 'no big deal, just got to re-install the drivers or something.
At first I just activated the fglrx from 'additional drivers' in system settings, just in case. Then I found a guide that told me to download _NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-313.30.run_, and afterward to enter TTY, log in and go to the directory that the file was in and input these commands:

sudo service lightdm stop

sudo chmod a+x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-313.30.run

sudo./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-313.30.run

Answer (score 1):

To get information about the GPU, you can run the commands:

```
sudo lshw -c display
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
```

The open source driver "nouveau" is used for nVidia cards by default.
The driver should be mentioned in the output of both commands. If the output of the first one mentions "UNCLAIMED", then there is no driver in use.

Comment: I don't have enough characters to post all the information that I got for the commands, the dvi cable is plugged in to the motherboard and according to the sudo lshw -c display command, it's a radeon. Neither report makes any mention of the nouveau or my card.

Comment: Are you sure that your GPU is nVidia? The fglxr (mentioned in a comment above) and radeon drivers are both for AMD/ATI graphics.

Comment: I'm staring long and intimately at the box the card came in, the sticker on the card itself, as well as the fancy bevelled writing on the casing of the card. I assure you, it's a NVidia. I turned on the fglrx because I figured, "Why not?"

Comment: How do I show you the information the commands gave back to me?

Comment: the other command provides too much information for me to be able to post up  
    
l0stth0ught@Navi:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780 [Radeon HD 3200] [1002:9610]
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:82f1]
 Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

Comment: This is something I've never heard before and I can't think of something. Maybe the ubuntuforums.org is a more suitable place to examine an issue like this. I would recommend that you create a thread there, giving detailed information about what you did (for instance, did you manually replaced the graphics card) and post the output of the above commands or any other that may be asked. The lspci command detects an AMD/ATI graphics card. Do you have both cards connected to the motherboard? AMD/ATI and nVidia?

Comment: I only bought the nvidia card, that's installed in the PCI-e slot(the only slot that it fits, btw). I can only assume that the ATI has to be a part of the motherboard's chipset. Either that, or my computer is schizophrenic. I installed the nvidia card myself, and I figure the standard dvi outlet on the motherboard is ATI, since it's the only way I can see what I'm typing